# Line Segment Raycasting Intersection as Cylinder

Tags: c++, opengl, math, raycasting, cylindrical

I'm writing an app in OpenGL and C++. I need to detect when the user clicks on a line segment with raycasting. However, because lines are only a pixel thick, I need to treat each line segment as a 3D cylinder to allow the user some leeway when clicking segments. How do I do this? I'm not very skilled at math so I can't grasp the high-level descriptions I'm finding on the internet. I've found a few algorithms, but these all assume the cylinder is situated on the origin and isn't rotated. I need a solution that will work for any orientation of a cylinder.

Comment: I am not sure if you need a cylinder, because it might require you a lot of additional work and calculations which you probably do not want. How about you do a [line-line distance test](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Distance_between_two_straight_lines)? Basically your mouse click is a ray from the view origin to whereever you clicked with a mouse. And the other line is obviously your given line.

Comment: It is probably even better to do the intersection in screen space because you want to define the tolerance in pixels.